# how to receive a callback in python fastapi unittest

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, callback, fastapi

```
import from fastapi import BackgroundTasks

def bar(item: Item, returnFlag: int, callbackUrl: AnyHttpUrl):
     requests.post(url=callbackUrl, headers=headers, data=someDataWithReturnFlag)
    

def foo(item: Item, callback_url: AnyHttpUrl):
    returnFlag = subprocess.run("a command that runs a subprocess and returns 0 or 1 or -1")
    bar(item, returnFlag, callback_url)

@app.put("/xyzservice")
def xyzservice(item: Item, background_tasks: BackgroundTasks, callback_url: AnyHttpUrl):
    background_tasks.add_task(foo, item, callback_url)
```

above code snippet adds a background task foo, foo calls bar with return Flag.
Now i need to write a unit test case for xyzservice and receive a callback from bar and assert that returnFlag == 1. I CANNOT modify the above code in my favor so it can be tested easily.

I tried to write test case as follows :

```
from fastapi.TestClient import TestClient

def test_xyzservice():
    item = {"some": "data", "somekey":"somevalue"}
    client = TestCase()
    response = client.put("/xyzservice"+"?"+callback_url, data=item)
    if(response.sattusCode == 200):
        #TODO: write code to get the returnFlag that is sent to bar.
        #possible solution 1: receive callback from request made in bar() and read the return Flag
```

I simply want to know the returnFlag by receiving request made by bar()

Comment: a much simpler version of my problem might be put as follows

def bar(item: Item, returnFlag: int, callbackUrl: AnyHttpUrl):
     requests.post(url=callbackUrl, headers=headers, data=someDataWithReturnFlag)

how to catch or read request sent by bar() ??

Comment: You could try mocking `bar` or maybe even the `requests.post` method, and then check [assert_called_with](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#quick-guide)